# cuál sería la forma correcta de realizar una relación entre dos tablas para un club

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

hola a todos tengo una consulta, cuál sería la forma correcta de realizar una relación entre dos tablas para un club, tengo la tabla socios y la tabla clubes y al momento de registrar un nuevo socio, el socio puede pertenecer hasta tres clubes, yo cree las llaves foráneas tres veces, pero cuando quiero hacer una consulta y ver a que clubes pertenece un socio no se visualiza nada, al menos que las llaves foráneas sean iguales, a continuación ejemplo de mi select.

```
SELECT top 10       dbo.socios.idsocios, dbo.socios.numeroci, dbo.socios.nombres, dbo.socios.apellidos, dbo.socios.direccion, dbo.socios.idclubes1, dbo.clubes.denominacion, dbo.socios.idclubes2, dbo.clubes.denominacion, dbo.socios.idclubes3, dbo.clubes.denominacion
FROM            dbo.clubes INNER JOIN
                         dbo.socios ON dbo.clubes.idclubes = dbo.socios.idclubes1 AND dbo.clubes.idclubes = dbo.socios.idclubes2 AND dbo.clubes.idclubes = dbo.socios.idclubes3
```

solamente se muestra los datos si las llaves foráneas son iguales. también pensé en registrar el mismo socio tres veces, pero al cliente no le gusta que exista tres registros, el quiere registrar en un mismo registro. Entonces, cual sería la forma correcta de realizar este paso? si por favor puedan ayudarme, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> También pensé en registrar el mismo socio tres veces, pero al cliente
> no le gusta que exista tres registros, el quiere registrar en un mismo
> registro.

El cliente tiene razón, las bases de datos relacionales deben normalizarse para evitar duplicados. Pero tener tres campos para guardar los clubes del cliente también es un mal diseño.

Lo ideal sería agregar una tabla que relacione el socio son los clubes a los que pertenece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la consulta sería así:

```
select * from 
socios as s 
join clubesSocio as c
      on s.id = c.socioid
join clubes cl on cl.id = c.clubid
```

**Proceso de inserción**

La inserción debe hacerse en una transacción ya que son dos tablas las involucradas.

Primero hay que insertar el registro en la tabla `socios`, luego recuperar el `id` que se generó para ese registro.

Segundo insertar los registros en la tabla `clubesSocio`, uno por cada club al que pertenece el socio.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero aún me queda una duda, cómo insertaría los registros? suponiendo que al insertar un socio debo seleccionar que pertenece a tres clubes distintos, entonces, como guardo las informaciones de las llaves foráneas? estoy tratando de entender pero mi mente está rebobinando :(

Comment: Agregué una pequeña explicación del proceso de inserción a la respuesta.